# MVC 4 Paging Searching

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have applied search method in my project but , I have also Action index()
and getting erorr. (The current request for action 'Index' on controller type 'AdultLiteracyTeachersController' is ambiguous between the following action methods:)

```
public ViewResult Index(string searchstring, string currentFilter, int? page)
            {

                if (searchstring != null)
                {
                    page = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    searchstring = currentFilter;
                }
                ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchstring;
                var teachers = from r in db.AdulLiteracyTeachers select r;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchstring))
                {

                    teachers = teachers.Where(r => r.ALTName.ToUpper().Contains(searchstring.ToUpper()));

                }

                teachers = teachers.OrderBy(r => r.ALTName);
                int pagesize = 10;
                int pageNo = (page ?? 1);

                return View(teachers.ToPagedList(pageNo, pagesize));
            }
```

The other ActionResult.index()

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var adulliteracyteachers = db.AdulLiteracyTeachers.Include(a => a.District);
            return View(adulliteracyteachers.ToList());
        }
```

Action result is used for calling all data how can I aplly in single index ?

Answer (score 0):

Combine them:

```
        public ViewResult Index(string searchstring, string currentFilter, int? page)
        {
            if (searchString == null && currentFilter == null && !page.HasValue)
            {
                // No parameters
                var adulliteracyteachers = db.AdulLiteracyTeachers.Include(a => a.District);
                return View(adulliteracyteachers.ToList());
            }

            // Regular code here down
            if (searchstring != null)
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                searchstring = currentFilter;
            }
            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchstring;
            var teachers = from r in db.AdulLiteracyTeachers select r;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchstring))
            {

                teachers = teachers.Where(r => r.ALTName.ToUpper().Contains(searchstring.ToUpper()));

            }

            teachers = teachers.OrderBy(r => r.ALTName);
            int pagesize = 10;
            int pageNo = (page ?? 1);

            return View(teachers.ToPagedList(pageNo, pagesize));
        }
```

Comment: I have apllied now getting error " he model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[LiteracyPayroll.Models.AdulLiteracyTeachers]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'PagedList.IPagedList`

Comment: Your model binding is broken. I can't help a lot with that, you must understand that your application expects one particular type in the model, and you're giving it a different type.